# Cannot left align text input having awesome icons close to them

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to align 2 input text that have awesome icon close to them.

```
<span i class="fa fa-link fa-lg">
    <input id="product" type="text" placeholder="Product" required/>            
</span>
<br><br>
<span i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg">
    <input id="desktop" type="text" placeholder="Desktop" required/>            
</span>
```

[image]

I would like to have the inputs left aligned independently to the width of the icon.

Comment: they are already left aligned..!! can't get what actually u need ?

Comment: what if you add 'fa-fw' class to both the icons?
That defines a fixed width on the icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fa-fw` font-awesome utility class.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span> 
<i class="fa fa-link fa-fw fa-lg"></i>
<input id="product" type="text" placeholder="Product" required/>            
</span>
<br>
<br>
<span> 
<i class="fa fa-desktop fa-fw fa-lg"></i>
<input id="desktop" type="text" placeholder="Desktop" required/>            
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make the icons a distinct element by themselves so that they can form a block element with a fixed width.

The either structure should be the following:

```
<span> 
    <i class="fa fa-link fa-lg"></i>
    <input id="product" type="text" placeholder="Product" required/>            
</span>
<br><br>
<span>
    <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg"></i>
    <input id="desktop" type="text" placeholder="Desktop" required/>            
</span>
```

And give fixed width to the font awesome icons:

```
i {
   width: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: There is no real need to add any new CSS. Just make use of the fontawesome utility class 'fa-fw' (as mentioned in fontawesome docs http://fontawesome.io/examples/#fixed-width)

Comment: @seemly Yeah, but giving customized css makes your code more flexible to requirements. What if I don't want a `width: 1.28571429em` but something else. :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your HTML is invalid.

Be sure to make use of the fontawesome utility class of `fa-fw` to apply a fixed width to the icon. (fixed-width as mentioned in docs: http://fontawesome.io/examples/#fixed-width)

Try the following code (as per example: https://jsfiddle.net/0vwfp6e2/1/):

```
<label>
    <i class="fa fa-link fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
    <input id="product" type="text" placeholder="Product" required/>  
</label>

<label>
    <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
    <input id="desktop" type="text" placeholder="Desktop" required/>
</label>
```